# My phone name is HTC desire 820g plus. whenever i receive a bluetooth file my phone says "magic.why?

Tags: htc-desire, voice-command

My phone name is HTC desire 820g plus I bought the phone yesterday..whenever I receive a blue-tooth file my phone says magic or image I am not sure what exactly it says,but it talks.I tried to disabe talk back and google voice but still it wont work.even when I keep my phone on silent mode it still talks very disturbing please help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a "feature" that HTC builtin you might try looking around in the Bluetooth settings to see if there is any sort of thing about notification etc.